# Colar um texto tratado aonde o ponteiro está

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tenho o seguinte problema:

> Algumas pessoas do meu trabalho copiam textos de alguns words e colam nos formulários
>   que eu faço (dentro do GED), porem algumas vezes nesse copiar e colar ele levam com o texto alguns caracteres inválidos, como por exemplo
>   essa aspas: “

Eu tive a ideia de capturar o colar, tratar ele e depois colar o texto tratado.
Segue o código:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 var clipboardData, pastedData;
 $(":input").on("paste", function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
   clipboardData = e.clipboardData || window.clipboardData;
      pastedData = clipboardData.getData('text');
   // smart single quotes and apostrophe
   pastedData = pastedData.replace(/[\u2018\u2019\u201A]/g, "\'");
   // smart double quotes
   pastedData = pastedData.replace(/[\u201C\u201D\u201E]/g, "\"");
   // ellipsis
   pastedData = pastedData.replace(/\u2026/g, "...");
   // dashes
   pastedData = pastedData.replace(/[\u2013\u2014]/g, "-");
   this.value += pastedData;
 });
});
```

Eu usei na hora de colar depois de tratado o "value +=" porem nesse caso, sempre que alguém colocar o ponteiro no meio de um texto já digitado, ele vai ignorar aonde o ponteiro está e vai "colar" o conteúdo do paste tratado no final do texto. Como eu posso colocar o conteúdo do paste tratado onde o ponteiro está?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aparentemente consegui achar uma solução para o problema:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 var clipboardData, pastedData;
 $(":input").on("paste", function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  clipboardData = e.clipboardData || window.clipboardData;
  pastedData = clipboardData.getData('text');
  var hist = pastedData;
  // smart single quotes and apostrophe
  pastedData = pastedData.replace(/[\u2018\u2019\u201A]/g, "\'");
  // smart double quotes
  pastedData = pastedData.replace(/[\u201C\u201D\u201E]/g, "\"");
  // ellipsis
  pastedData = pastedData.replace(/\u2026/g, "...");
  // dashes
  pastedData = pastedData.replace(/[\u2013\u2014]/g, "-");
  //alert(pastedData+" != "+hist);
  if (document.selection) {
   //For browsers like Internet Explorer
   this.focus();
   var sel = document.selection.createRange();
   sel.text = pastedData;
   this.focus();
  }else if (this.selectionStart || this.selectionStart == '0') {
   //For browsers like Firefox and Webkit based
   var startPos = this.selectionStart;
   var endPos = this.selectionEnd;
   var scrollTop = this.scrollTop;
   this.value = this.value.substring(0, startPos)+pastedData+this.value.substring(endPos,this.value.length);
   this.focus();
   this.selectionStart = startPos + pastedData.length;
   this.selectionEnd = startPos + pastedData.length;
   this.scrollTop = scrollTop;
  } else {
   this.value += pastedData;
   this.focus();
  }
 });
});
```

> Fonte: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/946534/insert-text-into-textarea-with-jquery

Answer (score 3):

Você vai precisar trabalhar com `Selection Ranges`.

Aqui essa função vai inserir os valores a partir da posição do ponteiro:

```
function insertAtCursor(myField, myValue) {
    //IE support
    if (document.selection) {
        myField.focus();
        sel = document.selection.createRange();
        sel.text = myValue;
    }
    //MOZILLA and others
    else if (myField.selectionStart || myField.selectionStart == '0') {
        var startPos = myField.selectionStart;
        var endPos = myField.selectionEnd;
        myField.value = myField.value.substring(0, startPos) +
            myValue +
            myField.value.substring(endPos, myField.value.length);
    } else {
        myField.value += myValue;
    }
}
```

Agora substitua `this.value += pastedData;` por `insertAtCursor(this, pastedData);` no seu script.

> Fonte:
>   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11076975/insert-text-into-textarea-at-cursor-position-javascript#answer-11077016

Comment: Opa, funcionou aqui! Vlw